# How to explicitly set django_language in django session

Tags: django

How to explicitly set `django_language` in `Django` session?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you want your users to be able to specify language, make sure that `LocaleMiddleware` is enabled:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   ...
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   ...
)
```

Then Django will look for the user's language preference in that order (see `get_language_from_request` in [trans_real.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py)):

1. in `request.path_info`, if [i18n_patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns) are used
2. `request.session[settings.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]` ([DEPRECATED](https://github.com/django/django/commit/a8e2a9bac6e548d6ab2e13af6171d2fdd3b8055b) in Django 3.0, removed in Django 4.0)
3. `request.COOKIES[settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME]`
4. every language in `request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`, until accepted one is found
5. `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`.

**As of Django 4.0**

The most straightforward way to set language explicitly in Django session is to activate and set the cookie, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import translation

user_language = 'fr'  # example
translation.activate(user_language)

# persist using the cookie
response = HttpResponse(...)
response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, user_language)
```

**Before Django 4.0**

The most straightforward way to set language explicitly in Django session is to rewrite `request.session[settings.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]`:

```
def someview (request):
    ...
    request.session[settings.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = 'en'
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, i did exactly like this before but it didn't work, it turned out i used a language tag not in defualt LANGUAGES list, it  is cool now.

Thanks

Comment: Not to mention the handy [`django.views.i18n.set_language()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/i18n/internationalization/#the-set-language-redirect-view) builtin view

Comment: It is more reliable to use `LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY` from  `django.utils.translation` for name of the session's key

Comment: Please update answer for Django >= 1.7. request.session['django_language'] is deprecated. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#internationalization

Comment: Is this statement: "Then Django will look for the user's language preference in that order (see get_language_from_request in trans_real.py):"  still valid? Is this true for Django 3? I checked the provided link https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py and I see no occurrence of LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY. Also, if you look into Django 3 docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference there is no reference to the session variable, it just check i18n, cookie, HTTP header and then the fallback.

Answer (score 21):

And if you will use a version `>= Django 1.8`. Here it is how we could use that:

```
from django.utils.translation import LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY

def someview (request):
    ...
    request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = 'en'
```

Comment: This works more consistently as settings might not have the property `LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY`

Comment: Does not work anymore, should use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language instead

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [django.views.i18n.set_language()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n//translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view). Activate this view by adding the following line to your URLconf:

```
# This example makes the view available at /i18n/setlang/
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

> As a convenience, Django comes with a view,
>   `django.views.i18n.set_language()`, that sets a user’s language
>   preference and redirects to a given URL or, by default, back to the
>   previous page.
>
> The view expects to be called via the POST method, with a language
>   parameter set in request. If session support is enabled, the view
>   saves the language choice in the user’s session. Otherwise, it saves
>   the language choice in a cookie that is by default named
>   `django_language`. (The name can be changed through the
>   `LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME` setting.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to follow Django documentation:

in your urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other libraries
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]
```

and in your template file (ex: "/core.html") just call de standard "set_language" view. I'll go for a boostrap switcher:

```
   {% load i18n %}
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="nc-icon nc-planet"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
            {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
            {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
            {% for lang in languages %}
                <button type="submit"
                        name="language"
                        value="{{ lang.code }}"
                        class="dropdown-item">
                    {{ lang.name_local }}
                </button>
            {% endfor %}
            </form>
            </ul> 
        </li>
    </ul>
```