# Adapt translation method from django to my function

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project. I have created a function that will display the current date in french or english.

We have to install

```
sudo locale-gen fr_FR.utf8
```

and then

```
from datetime import datetime
import locale

def set_locale(locale_):
    locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL, locale=locale_)


def date_customerprofile(language):
    now_ = datetime.today()
    if language == 'English':
        set_locale('en_US.utf8')
        date_ = now_.strftime("%A %B %d %Y")
    else:
        set_locale('fr_FR.utf8')
        date_ = now_.strftime("%A %B %d %Y")
```

I know it works well, but I would like to use the django translation method. There are good informations here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/ and in particular here : https://www.technomancy.org/python/django-i18n-manually-turn-on-a-language/.

Could anyone be able to adapt the last website method to my function?

I tried something but that doesn't work :

```
from django.utils import translation

def date_customerprofile(language):
    now_ = datetime.today()
    old_lang = 'en'
    if language == 'English':
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        translation.activate('en')
        date_ = now_.strftime("%A, %B %d %Y")
    else : 
        translation.activate('fr')
        date_ = now_.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")
        translation.activate(old_lang)
    return date_
```

In fact, my main purpose is to create a function which will display the current date of the form `Mercredi, 29 mars 2017` when I select `'French'` and the form `'Wednesday, March 29, 2017'`. Could anyone have an idea how to do that with a django method?

Thanks!

**P.S.** Please let me know if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.strftime()` is a method from the Python standard library and doesn't know anything about your Django language. You can use the builtin [`date` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date) which does respect the Django language.

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.template.defaultfilters import date as datefilter
from django.utils import translation

def date_customerprofile(language):
    now_ = datetime.today()
    if language == 'English':
        translation.activate('en')
        return datefilter(now_, 'l, F j, Y')
    else:
        translation.activate('fr')
        return datefilter(now_, 'l, j F Y')
```

Seems to give the results you want:

```
>>> date_customerprofile('English')
u'Thursday, March 30, 2017'
>>> date_customerprofile('French')
u'jeudi, 30 mars 2017'
```

Some notes:

- If this is used in the context of one user who has one language, it would be better to [set the language on the user's sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605384/how-to-explicitly-set-django-language-in-django-session) rather than switch it around just within this function.
- If you were really serious about localization you would put your custom date formats in [format files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files) but it may be overkill for your use case.