# Django language session not existing

Tags: django, translation

I have made a website which supports two languages at the moment. It has been made with `django.utils.translation` (Using makemessages and compilemessages). The site is working fine locally on my own machine, and translating correctly. When i pull the code on the website server (and restart the app) it gives the following error:

```
`Internal Server Error: /da/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myname/.virtualenvs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/myname/.virtualenvs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/myname/.virtualenvs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/myname/myname/myname_django/home/views.py", line 62, in index
    'value': get_value(request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY]),
  File "/home/myname/.virtualenvs/myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
KeyError: '_language'`
```

So for some reason it cannot find the language session, but i have no clue why

Comment: Please check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605384/how-to-explicitly-set-django-language-in-django-session/33066651 this answer is better then mine, so i delete mine.

Comment: hmmm, the issue is  that it's working fine locally, and i have done all of the things he has listed .